# Maps Directions API - Zero Results only on a certain server

Tags: php, google-maps, directions

I'm making a call to the directions API, and on one server (where it was previously working without issue), I'm getting ZERO RESULTS returned. I have the same code locally, and results are returned without issues. I also get the expected results if I take the URL that the code is calling and visit it manually in a browser. I'm pretty stumped.

I've changed addresses for privacy sake.

```
$origin = urlencode('123 Fake St., London, ON, A0A 0A0');
$destination = urlencode('A0A 0A0');

// key removed for privacy
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='.$start.'&destination='.$finish.'&key=xxxx';
if($data = file_get_contents($url)) {
    // call is made without issue, but ZERO RESULTS is returned (only on one server).
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
    // do stuff
}
```

SSL is enabled on the server in question.

This was working everywhere up until today.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't hit some quota? Are you running this on Google App Engine? You can see if you've hit your quota for the day. When you say zero results, do you mean an empty array response `[]` or an empty server response?

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but it looks as though Google will return OVER_QUERY_LIMIT if you've reached your quota for the day. The actual response from file_get_contents($url) is NOT_FOUND ZERO_RESULTS ZERO_RESULTS

Answer (score 0):

I hate to admit it - but it would seem that a simple server reboot was all that I needed.

Always start with 'Have you tried turning it off and on again'...